# Tengo un problema con scraping web con python, al ordenar los datos en una hoja de excel

Tags: python, excel, scrapy

Tengo ya el codigo para raspar la pagina lo hace y me exporta en una hoja .txt o csv pero raspa absolutamente toda la pagina, como podria exportar en otro excel, pero q este de forma ordenada por casillas...

este es el codigo para raspar paginas..

```
import sys
import csv



if sys.version_info[0] == 3:
from urllib.request import urlopen
else:

from urllib import urlopen
f = csv.writer(open('0006.csv', 'w'))
sys.stdout = open('log02.txt', 'w')


with urlopen("https://www.ultracasas.com/") as url:
s = url.read()

print(s)
f.writerow([s])
```

aca esta una parte de como esta el .txt exportado

```
div class="col-sm-12 publication-element">\n    \n\n\n\n\n\n\n<div class="clp-premium-table-item" id="publication_2838448">\n  <div class="margin-left-0 margin-right-0 relative row">\n    \n    \n      <div class="col-sm-3 clp-search-image-container" style="position:relative;">\n        \n          <div class="new-premium-ribon-clp"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>Destacado</div>\n        \n        \n          <a href="/ver-publicacion/venta-usada/maipu/casa/pto-velero-maipu-maipu-chile/2838448">\n            <img src="/imagenes/publicacion/venta-usada/casa/maipu/0/22219928ABF9EC2C2F6E0F788056402F49BC30D68F3.jpeg"  alt="Venta propiedad usada / Casa / Maip\xc3\xba">\n          </a>\n          <div class="text-center">\n            <small>31/03/2019</small>\n          </div>\n        \n      </div>\n      <div class="col-sm-6">\n        <div>\n          <h2 class="publication-title-list">\n            <a href="/ver-publicacion/venta-usada/maipu/casa/pto-velero-maipu-maipu-chile/2838448">Maip\xc3\xba, Pto Velero, Maip\xc3\xba, Maipu, Chile</a>\n            \n          </h2>\n          \n        </div>\n        <div class="font-size-small">Tiene Living Comedor, 3 dormitorios, 2 ba\xc3\xb1os, antejardin, entrada de autos (para 3 veh\xc3\xadculos), jard\xc3\xadn posterior. Piso de cer\xc3\xa1mica en toda la propiedad, protecciones en las ventanas, condominio cerrado. Tiene restaurantes, supermercados y comercio en general cercano.</div>\n        <div>\n          <span class="light-bold">C&oacute;digo: </span>2838448<br>\n          <h3 class="sub-codigo-data">Venta propiedad usada / Casa / Maip\xc3\xba</h3>\n        </div>\n        \n          <div>\n            \n  \n\n<button type="button" onclick="toggeFavoriteFromListing(this, \'PUBLICATION\', 2838448);return false;" data-favorite="false" class="favorite-button btn btn-sm btn-raised ">\n  <span class="favorite-false">\n    <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>\n    <span>Agregar a favoritos</span>\n  </span>\n  <span class="favorite-true">\n    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>\n    <span>Quitar de favoritos</span>\n  </span>\n</button>\n\n          </div>\n        \n      </div>\n      <div class="col-sm-3 relative">\n        \n\n\n\n\n\n  \n    <a class="btn btn-raised btn-info btn-block margin-top-0 text-ellipsis" href="/ver-publicacion/venta-usada/maipu/casa/pto-velero-maipu-maipu-chile/2838448">\n      <span class="clp-value-container" value="8.0E7" data-no-value-unit valueUnit="1" areaUnit="">\n        80.000.000\n      </span>\n      \n      <span class="clp-value-container" data-no-value valueUnit="1" areaUnit="">\n        CLP\n      </span>\n    </a>\n  \n  \n    <small>\n      <span class="light-bold">Terreno:</span> 140 m&sup2;\n    </small><br>\n  \n  \n    <small>\n      <span class="light-bold">Superficie Construida:</span> 63 m&sup2;\n    </small><br>\n  \n  \n    <small>\n      <span class="light-bold">Habitaciones:</span> 3\n    </small><br>\n  \n  \n    <small>\n      <span class="light-bold">Ba&ntilde;os:</span> 2\n    </small><br>\n  \n  \n\n        \n      </div>\n    </div>\n  \n  \n</div>\n\n\n  </div>\n\n  \n  <div class="col-sm-12 publication-element">\n    \n\n\n\n\n\n\n<div class="clp-premium-table-item" id="publication_2838236">\n  <div class="margin-left-0 margin-right-0 relative row">\n    \n    \n      <div class="col-sm-3 clp-search-image-container" style="position:relative;">\n        \n          <div class="new-premium-ribon-clp"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>Destacado</div>\n        \n        \n          <a href="/ver-publicacion/venta-usada/lampa/casa/el-llano-valle-grande-lampa/2838236">\n            <img src="/imagenes/publicacion/venta-usada/casa/lampa/0/1254314EC9BE57DB52DB6B7E459CEC24A593BC56C72.jpeg"  alt="Venta propiedad usada / Casa / Lampa">\n          </a>\n          <div class="text-center">\n            <small>31/03/2019</small>\n          </div>\n        \n      </div>\n      <div class="col-sm-6">\n        <div>\n          <h2 class="publication-title-list">\n            <a href="/ver-publicacion/venta-usada/lampa/casa/el-llano-valle-grande-lampa/2838236">Lampa, El Llano, Valle Grande, Lampa</a>\n            \n          </h2>\n          \n        </div>\n        <div class="font-size-small">Ubicada en sector residencial, Valle Grande, Lampa. Sector con diversa gama de prestaciones y servicios, entre ellos colegios, supermercados, comercio en general. Cercana a Ruta 5 Norte, a minutos de estaci\xc3\xb3n de Metro Vespucio o Los Libertadores, Parque Industrial Valle Grande. Se vende equipada ...</div>\n        <div>\n          <span class="light-bold">C&oacute;digo: </span>2838236<br>\n          <h3 class="sub-codigo-data">Venta propiedad usada / Casa / Lampa</h3>\n        </div>\n        \n          <div>\n            \n  \n\n<button type="button" onclick="toggeFavoriteFromListing(this, \'PUBLICATION\', 2838236);return false;" data-favorite="false" class="favorite-button btn btn-sm btn-raised ">\n  <span class="favorite-false">\n    <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>\n    <span>Agregar a favoritos</span>\n  </span>\n  <span class="favorite-true">\n    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>\n    <span>Quitar de favoritos</span>\n  </span>\n</button>\n\n          </div>\n        \n      </div>\n      <div class="col-sm-3 relative">\n        \n\n\n\n\n\n  \n    <a class="btn btn-raised btn-info btn-block margin-top-0 text-ellipsis" href="/ver-publicacion/venta-usada/lampa/casa/el-llano-valle-grande-lampa/2838236">\n      <span class="clp-value-container" value="6.0E7" data-no-value-unit valueUnit="1" areaUnit="">\n        60.000.000\n      </span>\n      \n      <span class="clp-value-container" data-no-value valueUnit="1" areaUnit="">\n        CLP\n      </span>\n    </a>\n  \n  \n    <small>\n      <span class="light-bold">Terreno:</span> 109 m&sup2;\n    </small><br>\n  \n  \n    <small>\n      <span class="light-bold">Superficie Construida:</span> 53 m&sup2;\n    </small><br>\n  \n  \n    <small>\n      <span class="light-bold">Habitaciones:</span> 2\n    </small><br>\n  \n  \n    <small>\n      <span class="light-bold">Ba&ntilde;os:</span> 1\n    </small><br>\n  \n  <span class="light-bold">Amoblado:</span> S&iacute;<br>\n\n        \n          <a href="/ver-corredora/1254341/dubois-propiedades/0" class="imagen-corredora-list-clp">\n            <img src="/imagenes/corredoras/0/12543417FD0FF2254657DA5C2EF803FCF13717A7EF1.png" alt="Dubois Propiedades" title="Dubois Propiedades">\n          </a>\n        \n      </div>\n    </div>\n  \n  \n</div>\n\n\n  </div>\n\n   \n  <div class="col-sm-12">\n    <div>\n      <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>\n      <!-- Between search results -->\n      <ins class="adsbygoogle"\n      style="display:block;width: 100%;"\n      data-ad-client="ca-pub-1705857530403842"\n      data-ad-slot="4765816815"\n      data-ad-format="auto"></ins>\n      <script>\n      (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});\n      </script>\n    </div>\n  </div>\n  \n
```

Answer (score 0):

El web scraper que quieres hacer lleva mucho mas trabajo que el que tu tienes actualmente hecho.
Al hacer la petición mediante `urlopen` el servidor te está trayendo el contenido en HTML de la página, no los datos ya estructurados para CSV.
Te recomiendo que revises el proyecto [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/). Es una gran herramienta y te ayudará a resolver tu problema.

Comment: si ya hice pero mira que tengo el problema q las paginas q necesito raspar no me deja ya sea pro problemas de error (302, 200) pero haciendo de esta manera si puedo bajarlas, el problema q se me presento ahora es ordenarlas en tablas... gracias

Comment: @craven 302 y 200 no son errores

Comment: estube trabajando con django dynamic scraper y al hacer el raspado me salieron como error 302 y debug 200 entro a la pagina pero no saco por eso me mando esos mensajes, si podrias aclararme un poco mejor acerca de esos mensajes me seria de gran ayuda en mi trabajo, ya q con otras paginas hace raspado normal pero no con las q me indican en el trabajo.

Comment: los mensajes 200 los devuelve cuando todo del lado del servidor salió bien y los 30x los devuelve cuando hay una redirección

Comment: Gracias...estoy solucionando ese problema..

Answer (score 0):

Debes realizar una separación de las cadenas de html que te esta trayendo lo que ya haces; asignando las etiquetas de este a cada una de las variables que tienes.

Una idea es separar las lineas que hay por los '<'o '>' que suelen acompañar a los tags de html y extraer de esta forma el contenido.

Al hacer un barrido, podrás asignar casi de forma una a una las etiquetas con cada una de las variables y ahí si, poner estas a guardar en excel.